# Geth blockNumber is zero even if synced

Tags: go-ethereum

I have installed `geth` and I'm trying to launch geth console:

```
geth --rinkeby --datadir "D:\eth" console 2>> ./rinkeby.log
```

Which starts as:

```
instance: Geth/v1.8.16-stable-477eb093/windows-amd64/go1.11
coinbase: {omitted}
at block: 0 (Wed, 12 Apr 2017 20:59:06 +06)
datadir: D:\eth
modules: admin:1.0 clique:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

When I call `eth.syncing` which returns to me:

```
{
  currentBlock: 3648059,
  highestBlock: 3648151,
  knownStates: 9004305,
  pulledStates: 8990048,
  startingBlock: 3648020
}
```

When I try to call `eth.blockNumber` it returns to me `0`.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Hi there. Your node isn't synced. The `currentBlock` is still behind the `highestBlock`.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks That means I need to wait longer?

Comment: That's correct, yes. (I couldn't say how long though.)